# MVC - Unable to populate a view based off of dropdownlist selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC and ASP.NET in general so I am hoping someone can help put me in the right direction.

I am working on a site that allows a user to view certain records from a database by sorting them by date in a dropdown list.  I am having some problems.

I do not know how to let the user first get to the view and see no data, but be able to select a date from the drop down list and then see only the entries in the database that match the dropdown list.

Here is my controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HAPtest.Models;

namespace HAPtest.Controllers
{
    public class ViewerController : Controller
    {
        private LIVEASPNETDBEntities db = new LIVEASPNETDBEntities();



        public ActionResult Index(string dateString)
        {


            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> byDate = db.HapRecords
            .ToList()
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = c.Payment_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                Text = c.Payment_Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
            });



            ViewBag.ByDate = byDate;




            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateString))
            {
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
                ViewData["display"] = db.HapRecords.Where(c => c.Payment_Date ==     dt).ToList();

            }




            return View();


        }
```

And here is the code for my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<HAPtest.Models.HapRecord>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hap Records By Date";
}

<div id="DataDisplay">
    <h2>Hap Records By Date</h2>

    @using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Viewer")) {
    @Html.DropDownList("byDate", new SelectList(ViewBag.ByDate, "Value", "Text"))
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
     } 




<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RefNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payment_Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payment_Method)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payment_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payment_Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Party_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name_of_Payee)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trans_Code)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trans_Amount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.F_Initial)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.L_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_Box)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_Street1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_Street2)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_State)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corr_Zip)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UploadDateTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UploaderUserName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RefNum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Method)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Party_Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name_of_Payee)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Trans_Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Trans_Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.F_Initial)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.L_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_Box)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_Street1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_Street2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_State)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Corr_Zip)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadDateTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploaderUserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.HapRecordId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.HapRecordId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.HapRecordId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

</div>
```

When I have the code like this, I am getting an error: System.NullReferenceException and this is due to the fact that my Model is NULL in this view.  However, I do not know how to populate the view with the updated records each time a user selects a date from dropdown list.

Thanks in advance for the help in getting me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a couple of things to get you on a right track. Please do not treat that as a ready solution - these are just guidlines.

1. Your View is strongly typed, which is good. However for it to work properly you need to supply it with model. This is done in controller:

   ```
   var model = db.HapRecords.Where(c => c.Payment_Date == dt).ToList();
   return View(model);
   ```
2. You still want to support both cases in your view: when page is just opened and when something is submitted via drop down. This part is fine in your code:

   ```
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateString))
   {
       DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
       var model = db.HapRecords.Where(c => c.Payment_Date == dt).ToList();
       return View(model);
   }
   else
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. On the view you need to handle the case when there is no model, that is model is null. And do not show anything in this case probably:

   ```
   @if (Model != null)
   {
       <table class="table">
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Think about what you would like to do when there is no records in Model but it is not null. If you still would like to show nothing - you might need to switch from `IEnumerable` to `IList` to have `Count` property avaialble fo usage.
5. Also note that here:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RefNum)
   ```

   You are actually trying to retrieve `RefNum` from `IEnumerable`. You might have wanted (of course if Model contains any records) that:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].RefNum)
   ```
6. Controller accepts parameter with name `dateString`, which DropDown is named `byDate`. Decide on one or the other - in ASP.NET MVC parameter names matter.
7. DropDown and the Update button should be wrapped on a form which submits to `Viewer/Index` url, unless you did not show us the actual way you submit the drop down value to server.

Comment: Yes - yes this is exactly the direction I needed to take.  I created an if statement to handle Model == null like you said, and this took care of my nullreference exception.  I also changed my dropdown parameter to match the parameter dateString from my controller, and this allows me to update the view perfectly. Thank you very much. When my rating is higher I will also upvote your answer.